# How do I avoid a potentially dangerous Request.Form value?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

First of all, I know that there are dozens of questions similar to mine, but I didn't find any solution that would satisfy me...

So, I am getting the above exception on this code:

```
var returnUrl = Request.Params["returnUrl"] ?? Request.RawUrl;
```

After I submitted a post to my website, the mvc started preparing response page, and it crashes on the above code. Now, both of those variables do not contain any code that would cause this exception. Somehow MVC detects that I am using `Request` objects and throws an error without looking what am I doing. I don't want disabling those safety checks, but I don't know what else can I do?

Comment: So you expect that particular request to not trigger the validation? Or you expect validation to happen much earlier in request processing?

Comment: Can you give an example of what is in the returnUrl?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: I would like the validation to occur as normal, but not throw anything **in this particular line of code**. Why? Because `Request.Params["returnUrl"]` is null, and `Request.RawUrl` is `/Forums/AddPost/12311`, so there is nothing to throw an error for. Of course Request.Form has dangerous code, but it is not used in the line of code that throws this error. I think this is some kind of a bug or something here...

Comment: I don't believe you can selectively prevent validation for one particular field... My guess why exception happens - looks like lazy evaluation of `Params` - this line of code probably the very first line where ASP.Net needed to look at post body...

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the complete stack trace?

Comment: I've also just run into this issue. I'm already using `[AllowHtml]` and it's fine for the actual model binding (no errors), but if you then try to access the `Request` params directly, the error returns, generating from the line where `Request` params were accessed. Definitely seems like a bug (MVC 5)

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue and just found the solution. When you access posted values from `Request`, the values are re-validated and for some reason `[AllowHtml]` is ignored in this particular validation (perhaps a bug, tested in MVC 5). After a little searching, I stumbled upon:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh882339(v=vs.110).aspx

Down the page a bit, under the section "Disabling Request Validation in ASP.NET MVC", it mentions `Request.Unvalidated`. This property returns the request object while bypassing validation, so that you can then get at a particular param without invoking validation.

So instead of using `Request.Params["returnUrl"]`, use  `Request.Unvalidated["returnUrl"]`.

Comment: I'm upvoting you even though Request.Unvalidated.Params["returnUrl"] doesn't compile for me.  The alternative syntax worked Request.Unvalidated["returnUrl"] although it does sound like it will go through various sources for the parameter.

Comment: Looks like I forgot to add parenthesis after `Unvalidated`. See the updated code.

Comment: Note that if you have multiple parameters, you must call Request.Unvalidated for each parameters (even if there is only one unsafe parameter). The security check is done on all the collection values as soon as you call the getter Request.Params.

Answer (score 1):

If you are binding the request to a model, you could add the `AllowHtml` attribute to the model property that needs it. That allows you to keep the protection on the rest of the model.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to access the unvalidated Request.Params in a ActionFilterAttribute and ended up writing this extension method that might help someone else. It should return essentially the same data as Request.Params collection but unvalidated. I am returning a dictionary but you could easily change that to a NameValueCollection if you prefer. This extension method is off of the request so I can access the ServerVariables collection since that is not available in the UnvalidatedRequestValuesBase class but is normally included in Params. It also does not support NameValueCollection.Values but only returns a single value which is slightly different than Params.

```
public static IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> UnvalidatedParams(this HttpRequestBase request)
{
    var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var unvalidated = request.Unvalidated;

    for (var i = 0; i < unvalidated.QueryString.Count; i++)
    {
        var name = unvalidated.QueryString.GetKey(i);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            continue;

        var value = unvalidated.QueryString.Get(i);
        dict[name] = value;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < unvalidated.Form.Count; i++)
    {
        var name = unvalidated.Form.GetKey(i);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            continue;

        var value = unvalidated.Form.Get(i);
        dict[name] = value;
    }

    var cookieCount = unvalidated.Cookies.Count;
    for (var i = 0; i < cookieCount; i++)
    {
        var cookie = unvalidated.Cookies[i];
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cookie?.Name))
            continue;

        dict[cookie.Name] = cookie.Value;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < request.ServerVariables.Count; i++)
    {
        var name = request.ServerVariables.GetKey(i);
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name))
            continue;

        var value = request.ServerVariables.Get(i);
        dict[name] = value;
    }

    return dict;
}
```